# Sketchware: Error in/storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/602/app/src/main/java/com/DbEditor/VictorChannel/PageEditActivity.java(at line 83)

Tags: sketchware

I am creating an apk in Sketchware. I am trying to create a .db file editor, but this apk requires me to create a file manager within it so that I can browse the .db file. I was guided by this tutorial: https:/ /youtu .be/OkiBwSrT5WY
But when compiling in my project it gives me an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYPVY.jpg)

3. Error in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/602/app/src/main/java/com/DbEditor/VictorChannel/PageEditActivity.java (at line 83)
   ","design"));
   Syntax error in token "","", @expected
4. Error in /storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/602/app/src/main/java/com/DbEditor/VictorChannel/PageEditActivity.java (at line 83)
   ","design"));
   String literal is not properly closed with a double quote

I tried to look in the code what the problem was, I tried to remove the quotes, it didn't work, then I removed the parentheses in the code, that didn't work either.
It doesn't work for me when trying to compile the apk directly from Sketchware it puts back quotes and parentheses it seems that it doesn't change anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4fAu.jpg)

I don't know what to do please
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please don’t share code by screenshot but use the code markups. To your question: Have you already tried to simply remove the erroneous code in line 83? It looks like some accidental copy paste dirt from line 73.

Answer (score 0):

((View)_toolbar.getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(_c));

getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(_c)));

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

ERROR in

```
/storage/emulated/0/.sketchware/mysc/608/app/src/main/java/com/gaming/time/araf/MainActivity.java (at line 282)
    try {android.content.pm.PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(Package_Name, android.content.pm.PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES); Versions = pinfo.versionName; }catch (Exception e){ showMessage(e.toString()); }
                                                                                                                                                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).